# The string contain "/" can't be compared in android?

Tags: android, nanohttpd

I think Method A will displays "Ok", but in fact it displays "Fails". The Method B can get the correct result "OK".

I'm sure that the function `fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD.getMimeTypeForFile("my.css")` will return the result "text/css".

I don't understand why the Method A can't get correct result.  Is there some bugs with the function `fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD.getMimeTypeForFile` ?

BTW, Method C can get the correct result "OK".

**Method A**

```
String a="text/css";
String b= fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD.getMimeTypeForFile("my.css");

Utility.LogError("B: "+b);

if (a==b){
    Utility.LogError("Ok");
}else{
    Utility.LogError("Fails");
}
```

**Method B**

```
   String a="text/css";
    String b= fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD.getMimeTypeForFile("my.css");

    Utility.LogError("B: "+b);

    if (a.compareTo(b)==0){
        Utility.LogError("Ok");
    }else{
        Utility.LogError("Fails");
    }
```

**Method C**

```
   String a="text/css";
   String b= "text/css";

    Utility.LogError("B: "+b);

    if (a==b){
        Utility.LogError("Ok");
    }else{
        Utility.LogError("Fails");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Method 1

It results to "Fails"
**It because the actual objects on heap are getting compared when you use ==**
reference : [Detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7520464/1270865)

> Method 2

It results in Ok as a and b contain same text(mime type) in them (using compare to)

> Method 3

It results in Ok, as expected.

Comment: Thanks! but in fact Method 2 display "OK"

Comment: Oh yes, actually i did not consider what your method returned.. updated

Answer (score 1):

In method A , you judge "a==b" which means a have the same  reference as b.Obviously their reference is different.

Answer (score 1):

Beacause , In the case A,  "if(a == b)",a is a memory address ,as the same, b is a memory address ,ofcourse they are not the same !
and In the case B,you compare to a & b 's value! so they are the same .

Answer (score 0):

To compare strings in Java you must use equals().

```
String a = "abc";
String b = "abc";

if(a.equals(b)) {
// true!
}
```

When you use ==, java is comparing objects references, not its value.